# Applying a XSLT on multiple files as if they were merged

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question regarding the capabilities of xslt.  I have a bunch of different xml files that all share a common xslt transformation which converts them to html.  However, just applying the transformation on the individual xml files doesn't pull in all of the information about them.  Some of the files have other shared xml files that help define them.  So, I need to be able to perform the transformation on all of these files as if they were a single file without actually merging the files.

For example, We have a transformation file called "transform.xslt". We'll call a shared xml file "common.xml" and a regular xml file "a.xml."  We have another xml file "b.xml" and another shared file "other.xml".  In order to transform a.xml effectively, common.xml and a.xml need to have the transformation defined in transform.xslt performed on them as if they were a single file.  Similarly, to effectively transform b.xml, common.xml, b.xml, and other.xml all need to be transformed as if they were a merged single file.  I am really wondering if I can create xslt files that import the transformation xslt and specify which files need to act together as one.  That way, I could make an a.xslt, b.xslt, etc, that would perform the transformation of transform.xslt but on varying groups of files and would result in a single output for each xslt (a.html, b.html, etc).

If it would help anyone, the specific use case is to create documentation pages for WSDLs.  Some extra information, such as common data structures and types, is declared in a common.xsd.  Further, some of the WSDLs reference other XSDs that not every WSDL references.

I also really apologize if this question is unclear.  For some reason, I'm having a rather hard time articulating exactly what it is that I want to do.  Here's an outline of sorts that visualizes what I am thinking

For case 1:

- Input (defined in a.xslt)

  - a.xml
  - common.xml
- Transformation (imported in a.xslt)

  - transform.xslt
- Output

  - a.html

For case 2:

- Input (defined in b.xslt)

  - b.xml
  - common.xml
  - other.xml
- Transformation (imported in b.xslt)

  - transform.xslt
- Output

  - b.html

If anyone is still confused, please let me know.  I will try my best to explain more clearly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an XPath function named `doc` (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-doc)) that allows you to hold the contents of a file in an `xsl:variable`. You can then operate on the variable, i.e. pass it to `<xsl:apply-templates>`, or apply an XPath expression to it.
If you need more concrete help, post a sample of your actual data and I'll set up the XSLT for you. Are you using XSLT/XPath version 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: I'm using version 2. So, for the first example, would I essentially do `<xsl:variable name="file1" select="document('a.xml')"/>` `<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('common.xml')"/>` for the variables, then?  And how would I apply the template to both of those files (doesn't select specify the nodes, not the variables to apply to?)  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Another thing I was wondering is, how exactly would I execute this?  Typically, with xslt files, you specify the xml and the xslt and the engine will run the transform.  In this case, the xslt file specifies the file it wants to run on.  However, the parameter for the xml file is still necessary when executing (Java throws a null pointer exception if the xml parameter is null).  Is there a way around that?

Comment: About your first question, you can do `<xsl:apply-templates select="($file1, $file2)">`. Or `select="($file1/*, $file2/*)"`, or combine the nodes from the files with the union operator if that is more appropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: About your second question, if I understand correctly, you mean the actual data comes from the files you pass to `doc`, and the main input XML file is redundant. Just pass any XML file as main input then and ignore it ;-) By the way, the `document` function you mention is fine, too; one is an XSLT function, and the other is an XPath function.

Comment: To put it short, the "file" variables have document node type, and you can work with those document nodes the same way you do with any other nodes, as if they were subtrees from a single input file.

Comment: That makes it much more straightforward.  Thanks again for the help!